# Firefox- How to change font size of items in folder on bookmarks toolbar?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, css, xul

Using Firefox v8.0.1 on OS X Lion v10.7.2

Is there a way to adjust the size of the font of the items that appear IN A FOLDER of the bookmarks toolbar?

I do NOT want to change the font size of the folders and items on the bookmarks toolbar, only those that appear within a folder.

I am sure there is some css code that I can put in userChrome or userContent but I have cannot figure out what it is. I tried the DOM inspector, but it does not work for the items in the folders of the bookmarks toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [DOM inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM_Inspector) to find the proper selectors, the following should work with [userChrome.css](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html):

```
.bookmark-item menupopup .menuitem-iconic {
    property: value !important;
}
```

**Example:**

*Note: this also affects nested bookmarks.*

[image: bookmarks]

---

### Update:

To style subfolders:

```
.bookmark-item menu {
    property: value !important;
}
```

[image: subfolders]

Comment: Pics look like from Windows version? I am on Mac, and unfortunately this has no effect. I already have a userChrome file with modifications in it, and adding the above does not appear to do anything, even after shutting down and restarting Firefox. I actually tried the DOM Inspector myself, but could not get past the items on the Bookmarks Toolbar itself (clicking on folder just gave me dom for folder and would not open it up) ... is there a trick to getting the folder to open so you can inspect the links inside?

Comment: @jsherk The operating system should not matter. Try adding the `!important` flag for the css property. It should work now.

Comment: By the way, I manually inspected the DOM tree to find the individual elements.

Comment: Awesome! That worked mostly ... the text is smaller now, but any sub-folder-names in the folder are still the original size. And I also want to know how to make the right-click menu text smaller as well (let me know if I should ask that as a new question).

Comment: @jsherk Please delete your new question that is nearly identical to this one. I will update my answer to include the CSS to also change the subfolders.

Comment: @jsherk Updated! :)

Comment: Awesome! You are the king of userChrome tweaks! And here is related tweek for anybody interested: http://superuser.com/questions/374998/firefox-how-to-change-font-size-of-right-click-context-menu

Answer (score 0):

I had one issue with the solution posted above.  I couldn't get it to work for me until, after random experimentation, I eventually tried adding an `*` before the `{`, and it was effective.  So what I ended up with, combining the font changes of both the bookmarks and the sub-folders, was the following code:

```
/* Bookmark folder fonts' */

.bookmark-item menupopup .menuitem-iconic * { font-size: 10pt !important; } 
.bookmark-item menu * {
    font-size: 10pt !important;
}
```