# Firefox- How to change font size of right-click context menu?

Tags: firefox, osx-lion, context-menu, css, xul

Using Firefox v9.0.1 on OS X Lion v10.7.2

In userChrome.css, how do I adjust the font size that appears in the context menu when you right-click on something (like a link) on a web page?

I tried DOM inspector but cannot decipher what I am looking for.

Related to this thread:
[Firefox- How to change font size of items in folder on bookmarks toolbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/373431/firefox-how-to-change-font-size-of-items-in-folder-on-bookmarks-toolbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS selector for the **Right-click** context menu is:

```
#contentAreaContextMenu * {
    property: value !important;
}
```

### Example:

[image: contextmenu]

Any more `userChrome.css` tweaks? :)

Comment: Sorry for late response... I do not seem to get emails when somebody responds to my questions! #contentAreaContextMenu menuitem {  font-size: 12px !important; } is what I needed. I have accepted your answer as correct. thanks