# CSS needed change font size items in bookmarks toolbar folder

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, css

Just found [Firefox- How to change font size of items in folder on bookmarks toolbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/373431/firefox-how-to-change-font-size-of-items-in-folder-on-bookmarks-toolbar)

Realize it's for an older Firefox version, which might not work in 57+, but want to give it a try there. Needing to change font size (currently too small) in bookmarks toolbar subfolders (nested items.) Seems the accepted answer is

.bookmark-item menu { property: value !important; }

but there is no reference to the value for font-size.

What should this CSS be in order to change the font size to e.g. 10px? Thank you.

Screenshot current appearance:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Anyone? Perhaps my first post wasn't clear. Need a workable CSS. font-size (e.g., font-size 10px) needs to be incorporated into:

.bookmark-item menu {
    property: value !important;
}

I have tried different possibilities, but can't get anything to work. Or perhaps someone will just want to discard the CSS as written above and write something entirely new.

(note: topic edited to more accurately reflect question)